# Mongoose Model#create occasionally returning Connection not document instance

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Occasionally (maybe one in ten times, and these times are pretty clustered together) Mongoose's Model#create passes a Connection into my callback rather than a document instance. There are no errors passed, it does this with promises too, and I've only been able to reliably get the error when running mocha tests.

For example, the following code

```js
User.create(data, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(data);
});
```

will (only occasionally) log an object of class Connection, like,

```js
result: { ok: 1, n: 0 },
  connection:
   { domain: null,
     _events: ...
```

rather than a created model instance. `err` is null and a `data` is exactly as expected (and identical to `data` when `user` *is* a model instance as expected).

With `node-inspector` I've managed to trace it down to mongoose's `.save` returning the `Connection` object, but now I'm at a loss. Specifying a journaled write concern has absolutely no effect. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a non-atomic pre-save callback that was modifying various other models!